# Pandas memoization

Tags: python, package, pandas, memoization

I have lengthy computations which I repeat many times. Therefore, I would like to use memoization (packages such as [jug](http://packages.python.org/Jug) and [joblib](http://packages.python.org/joblib/memory.html)), in concert with [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org). The problem is whether the package would memoize well Pandas DataFrames as method arguments.

Has anyone tried it? Is there any other recommended package/way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Author of jug here: jug works fine. I just tried the following and it works:

```
from jug import TaskGenerator
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


@TaskGenerator
def gendata():
    return pd.DataFrame(np.arange(343440).reshape((10,-1)))

@TaskGenerator
def compute(x):
    return x.mean()

y = compute(gendata())
```

It is not as efficient as it could be as it just uses `pickle` internally for the `DataFrame` (although it compresses it on the fly, so it is not horrible in terms of memory use; just slower than it could be).

I would be open to a change which saves these as a special case as jug currently does for numpy arrays: https://github.com/luispedro/jug/blob/master/jug/backends/file_store.py#L102

Comment: And what happens when you call `compute(gendata())`? Does it actually load the DataFrame from cache?

Comment: If ``gendata()`` was computed in a different process, then yes.

Comment: Is there any way to run jug with `python` command instead of `jug`?

Answer (score 4):

I use this basic memoization decorator, `memoized`. http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize

DataFrames are hashable, so it should work fine. Here's an example.

```
In [2]: func = lambda df: df.apply(np.fft.fft)

In [3]: memoized_func = memoized(func)

In [4]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 1000))

In [5]: %timeit func(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 124 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit memoized_func(df)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 us per loop
```

Looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "DataFrames are hashable"? `hash(pd.DataFrame([1,2,3]))` returns a different value if you call it twice.

Comment: The code for memoized checks collections.Hashable() before it tries to cache the data. But your comment is making me reconsider whether this works as intended.

Comment: DataFrame should probably raise in this case, I'll put up pr on github

Comment: They'll raise in 0.11.1 (!). You could probably overwrite `__hash__` to be id (which was basically what it did before I think.