# Python pandas parallel processing using jugs TaskGenerator

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

I am trying to read a pandas dataframe and perform certain operations and return the dataframe. I also want to multiprocess the operation to take advantage of multiple cores that my system has.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from jug import TaskGenerator
@TaskGenerator
def find_replace(input_path_find):
    start_time = time.clock()
    df_find = pd.read_csv(input_path_find)
    df_find.currentTitle=df_find.currentTitle.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9`~!|@#%&_}={:\"\];<>,./. -]",r'')
    #extra space
    df_find.currentTitle=df_find.currentTitle.str.replace('\s+', ' ')
    #length
    df_find['currentTitle_sort'] = df_find.currentTitle.str.len()
    #sort
    df_find = df_find.sort_values(by='currentTitle_sort',ascending=0)
    #reindx
    df_find.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    del df_find['currentTitle_sort']
    return df_find
```

When i pass the parameter which is CSV file i want to process

```
df_returned = find_replace('C:\\Users\\Dell\\Downloads\\Find_Replace_in_this_v1.csv')
```

I am getting some weird output

```
find_replace
Task(__main__.find_replace, args=('C:\\Users\\Dell\\Downloads\\Find_Replace_in_this_v1.csv',), kwargs={})
    In [ ]:
```

Any help? I basically want to save the output from the function

I have already checked the answer and it didn't work. Also, i am using pythono 2.7 and anaconda IDE [Pandas memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386415/pandas-memoization)

Answer (score 0):

This is a misunderstanding of how [jug](https://jug.readthedocs.io) works.

The result you are getting is, indeed a `Task` object, which you can run: `df_returned.run()`.

Usually, though, you would have saved this script to a file (say `analysis.py`) and called `jug execute analysis.py` to execute the tasks.

Comment: I have 4 questions for you 1)Where the .py file should be saved? i tried navigating to a different folder and executed it didn't work so i had to paste the py file in c\python\scrpit folder and navigate through cd command and execute it. 2) How do i save the output i got from df_returned.run() as this is a pandas dataframe and i want to write the csv to dekstop. 3) What if i have multiple nested functions, do i have to declare '@TaskGenerator' before every function? 4) How many core does it use/ i mean what if i want to use only 3 out of 4 cores for the function and leave 1 for nothing?

Comment: These are quite fundamental questions about how to use jug. I'd start with the tutorials first before trying to apply in the context of your problem. More specific questions are best asked as separate Qs here or on the jug-users mailing-list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jug-users)

Comment: Ok, how about only exporting the CSV part?